# Is there "Go To page" Functionality in trNgGrid

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I have requirement as to add GO TO PAGE or "Select Page Number" text box at bottom of grid. Does trNgGrid has any option available. 
[image]

For more details about this Grid. http://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Found some code reference in below link to add select option in Tr-NgGrid pagination. 
https://moonstorm.github.io/trNgGrid/release/#/Customizations_Global